# Twitter Typeahead doesn't work with input created dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I'm using [Twitter Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) to provide autocompletion for my text input.

When I create an input dynamically, `.typeahead()` doesn't display the hint UI unless it is called after the input control is attached to DOM.

This works:

```
var input1 = $('<input type="text" />');
$("#dynamic-container1").append(input1); /* (A) */
input1.typeahead(null, make_dataset());  /* (B) */
input1.focus();
```

This doesn't:

```
var input2 = $('<input type="text" />');
input2.typeahead(null, make_dataset());  /* (B) */
$("#dynamic-container2").append(input2); /* (A) */
input2.focus();
```

(Note order of lines marked `(A)` and `(B)`.)

Why does it happen? Is there a correct way to initialize Typeahead before its input is appended to the DOM?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joz0fn3m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append `input2.parent()` instead of just input2. Because typeahead is not just that input element but a structure like below. By just appending the input, typeahead is missing the structure it requires.

```
<span class="twitter-typeahead">
  <input type="text" class="tt-hint" readonly="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" style="..." >
  <input type="text" class="tt-input" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" style="...">
  <pre aria-hidden="true" style="..."></pre>
  <span class="tt-dropdown-menu" style="...">
    <div class="tt-dataset-1">
    </div>
  </span>
</span>
```

Here is the updated ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/joz0fn3m/1/)***

Hope this helps